# user-defined function for random number generator in C output incorrect

Tags: c, arrays, random

For this program we have to create a user defined function to return 25 random variables from a value of 60-100, but when I run the program all 25 values are the same. I'm pretty new at programming and I think the error resided in where the user-function is defined, because I think instead of running the variable 25 times, its just running once and printing that first value 25 times.  But I don't know how to actually go about fixing it :(

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int get_value (int Random);

int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));//to randomize the number after each run
    int Random = rand()%40+60;

    printf("These are the temperatures for the day\n");
    int temp[25], i;
    for (i=0; i<25; i++) 
    {
        temp[i] = Random; 
        printf("%d\n" ,temp[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_value (int Random)
{
    Random = rand() % 40 + 60;
}
```

Comment: Your code never generates 100 (60..99 is what it can generate).

Comment: `temp[i]= rand()%40+61;` Currently, say `Random = 79;`, then you do `temp[i]=Random;` 25 times -- scenery never changes...

Comment: thank you so much everyone! yeah the user defined function was necessary for the assignment and my understanding of them is pretty weak, also thanks for catching the small error in the range!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `get_value()` has not returned anything. The `Random` argument is a *copy* of the `Random`  which you (might have) passed. It's legitimate to overwrite a (non-const) function arguement, but it won't find it's way way to the caller. The second problem is that you never call this function anyway, you just repeat the first random number you generated.

I suggest you rewrite the function like this

```
int get_value (void)
{
    return rand()%41+60;        // range 60 to 100
}
```

and call it like this

```
temp[i] = get_value();
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign to `Random` once; then you copy its value each time through the loop, giving you the same value each time as reported.  You need to regenerate the random number with a new call to `rand()` on each iteration.  You're correct to call `srand()` only once; that is important.

Your function only generates values in the range 60..99, not 60..100 as required in the question.  The fix is trivial; use 41 instead of 40.

Of course, having the `get_value()` function is no help if you never call it.  OTOH, it doesn't use its input argument, and it doesn't return a value, so maybe it is just as well that you never use it.